# Why am i unable to connect to MYSQL database with PlayFrameworks

Tags: mysql, angularjs, database, playframework

I am trying to connect to a Mysql Database via Play frameworks . I have read a bunch of tutorials and i think i am doing it to the letter. How ever i am not getting the

"DataBase  'default' needs evolution - warning." Instead i get the playframework index page.(which means its running.Also i think it means the database is not conencted).

I have the following as my application.conf

```
bean.default = ["models.*"]

play.evolution{
db.default.enabled=true
}

db{
default.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hope"
default.username = root
default.password = ""

default.logSql = true
}
```

And the following as my build.sbt

```
 name := """myfirstapp"""
 organization := "any"

 version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

 lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava,PlayEbean)

 scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

 libraryDependencies += jdbc
 libraryDependencies += guice

 libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.41"
```

I am not sure what i am doing.
I am getting the following as the log.

```
(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

 [info] p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] initialized at 
 jdbc:mysql://localhost/hope
 [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
 [warn] o.h.v.m.ParameterMessageInterpolator - HV000184: 
 ParameterMessageInterpolator has been chosen, EL interpolation will not be 
 supported
 [info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see 
 <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):

play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
```

according to the database it is initializing to connect as well. but does not connect and does not give me any errors either. could someone tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: I guess the path to your entities is not recognized. With play 2.6 for Java, I use ebean.default = "..." and not bean.default = "..." Maybe this can help.

Comment: @gsprs does that mean that  i am unable to do so with this verison of play

Comment: I am not sure but you can just try with ebean and see if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

Use query parameter useSSL=false

E.g  "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useSSL=false"

Use upper version mysql connector.

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.12"